# Mu-metal Magnetic shielding

Tags: magnetic-fields

If I want to have a magnetic field only at only one point (or line) in the box.

If I will enclose the box with mu-metal and leave a  hole a few millimetres in size in it, will it work?

Thank you.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking. Hopefully I haven't changed the meaning

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no, you can't have a magnetic field at just one point.

The magnetic field needs to obey Maxwell's second equation, which is
$\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ in free space. 
The upshot of this means that for any closed (imaginary or real) surface, that there is no NET magnetic flux through the surface. The field pointing 'into' the surface is balanced by the field pointing 'out of' the surface.

In principle, you can produce a field that's confined in a cylinder (maybe what you mean by a line), but you will need to have a current distribution, you can't do this with a hole in a mu-metal box and an external field.